# accessing an object property that contains forward slashes

Tags: javascript

I have created JSON by using the `json_encode` PHP function. The key of one of the items of the array contains a forward slash and when the JSON is parsed, the object looks like this when output in Chrome's console.

```
Object
contact/allow_anonymous: "0"
menulayout: "horizontal"
pages/max_pages: "10"
primarycolour: "329e95"
websitelogo: "text"
```

My problem is that I can't seem to be able to access the value of the properties that have a forward slash in them.

Any ideas? Since javascript allowed me to create the object I would assume there is a way to retrieve the values.

Comment: Have you tried `myObject["contact/allow_anonymous"]`?

Comment: What did you write that didn't work? How was the object created?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use `myObject["key"]` instead of `myObject.key`:

```
alert(myObject["contact/allow_anonymous"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just replace the forward slash with ~1.

```
Instead of contact/allow_anonymous use contact~1allow_anonymous
```